# MatLab how to draw multiple bar graphs to the same plot

Tags: matlab

What I have is a set of data that I want to display as a bar graph. What my data is one piece of the main data set compared to the average of the entire set for three different categories. So basically, what I want is 6 different bar graphs superimposed onto the same axis, 3 for the user selected one, and an additional three for the averages of the entire data set. I can do a single graph just fine, but is there a command to put all the graphs on the same axis spaced out appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You could join your vectors vertically and then use [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html).

Edit: you can do transparency in `bar3` with `alpha(.5)`

Below is a quarter view... you can make it head on so that it has that "superimposed" effect you want.

[image: Bar3]